# How to intiliaze QTime in QT?

Tags: qt

I have this in my header file:

```
explicit AccessSchedule(QWidget *parent = 0,QString item = "",QTime timefrom )
```

How should `timefrom` be initialized?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a default time, you can write:

```
explicit AccessSchedule(QWidget *parent = 0,QString item = "", QTime timefrom = QTime(11, 45));
```

`timefrom` will represent 11:45. If you just put:

```
..., QTime timefrom = QTime());
```

`timefrom` will be a "null" time object, i.e. it's `isNull()` method will return true and `isValid()` will return false.

Comment: But how to initialize it in my header file if i dont intilaize it gives error "default argument missing for Qtime"

Comment: exactly as above. I hadn't pasted your whole function, just the end.

Comment: One more thing how to convert QTime to QString ?

Comment: this site is not a substitute for reading the [`QTime`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtime.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever considered using [QTime::currentTime()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtime.html#currentTime) as your default parameter ?
i.e

```
explicit AccessSchedule(QWidget *parent = 0,QString item = "",QTime timefrom=QTime::currentTime() )
```

This way you **don't** have to check if the object isValid() or  isNull() which I think makes
code more readable. But it is your call of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your function arguments are in wrong order. Arguments with default value should be ALWAYS at the end of argument list. Read this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/